# Confirmation flag action in for loop

Tags: for-loop, vim, substitution, flags, confirmation

Example:

```
  "create list of only certain linenumbers 
  ....

  "take action on these linenumbers
  for i in range(0,len(mylist)-1)

     exe mylist[i].'s/(mysearch)/\=substitute(submatch(0), ".", "", "ge")/gc'

  endfor
```

The confirmation flag works fine if I use `y` or `n` but doesn't work when I use `a` or `q` because it is within a for loop.
How can I capture the `a` and `q` flag in a confirmation dialogue and execute it for the entire for loop:
`a --> do a substitute for all other lines in for loop`
`q --> end for loop`

(I once asked something similar but did not found the solution)

Answer (score 1):

I was going to use `:global` to fill your line numbers, but it has the same result. Instead, you can do this

```
exe '%s#\v('.join(map(copy(lines), '"%".v:val."l"'), '|').')\zsPATTERN#REPL#gc'
```

The key to the solution is `:h /\%l` to restrict your matches to specific lines.

Comment: Hi Luc, I don't understand your answer very well. My linenumbers are actually in a list "mylist" When I push p.e. 3 times 'y' on my keyboard for 3 substitutions and want to change all others ('a') how do I adapt your solution?

Comment: You just have to change `PATTERN` to what your are replacing, and `REPL` by what you want to insert instead. I'm still using `:substitute`. It's just I use map and join to concert the list into a very specific leading pattern. Try with `echo` instead of `exe` to see what the command does.

Comment: I cannot adapt this solution because I have the substitute command in a for loop with a lot more code. I would like to find something like `if user has pushed 'a' --> change subsitute code from 'gc' to 'g'` and `if user has pushed 'q' --> break for loop`

Comment: Can't you have your for loop do what it must then built the list of all lines lines, and finally execute the substitute? If not, the only other solution is for you to implement your replacement "mode". It can be done. You'll have to play with `echohl StatusLineNC` and `:redraw`. See for instance my `BracketsManipMode` function in [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/blob/master/plugin/common_brackets.vim#L372)

Comment: I'm trying as you've indicated to create my own replacement mode doing this: `exe mylist[i].'s/(mysearch)/\=INCLUDE_Confirmation(submatch(0))/g' but even here it is not possible to use the command "continue" or "break", it returns these commands in the text. Don't know how to go on :(

Comment: You won't be able to use `:substitute`. You'll have to emulate it thanks to `search()`, `getline()`, `subtitute()`, `setline()`, and a dialog you'll have to program.